# How to set input focus to an application which is not in foreground in Windows?

Tags: user-interface, mfc, winapi

I want my application to capture input focus, whenever the mouse hovers over it. How do I do it in Windows?

Basically I dont want users to explicitly click on the application, or the taskbar icon before entering any text, when the application is not in foreground.

I tried the `SetForegroundWindow` API in the mouse hover notification, but that just flashes the icon in the taskbar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where the focus is supposed to go.  But if to the hovered window then fake a mouse click with SendInput().

Answer (score 0):

Try GetDlgItem(QTIDD_W01_0)->SetFocus(); //QTIDD_W01_0 is the window of the screen

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways you can make your window Active

1. Use **SetActiveWindow** API to make your window active.
2. Enumarate all the windows and get your window handle and make foreground window.
3. Use **AllowSetForegroundWindow** API which accepts processid as the parameter and makes that process as active.